# Wait for SQL statement to be true before continuing - Ansbible

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I'm installing a service with Vagrant/Ansible on a Ubuntu 15.10 server. The service uses a MySQL database that it starts to provision itself once it is booted. I need to wait until the server has booted enough that it has created the table I need to insert data in to before continuing with my Ansbile script.

I know about the wait_for task in Ansible but it doesn't look like it will let me query the DB and keep querying it until the table can be found.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: I'd `wait_for` MySQL port to be ready to accept connections, and then use a combination of `shell` to call mysql-script with `until`, `retry`, `delay`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any task can be made to wait for some condition by adding a [loop condition](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#do-until-loops) to it. For example, say you have a command that returns "1" when the table exists and "0" otherwise:

```
- name: Wait for Database Table
  command: Put the command here
  register: result
  until: result.stdout == '1'
  retries: 6
  delay: 10
```

This task would wait 1 minute, and every 10 seconds it will run the command and check to see if the value matches the condition. If it doesn't match after all attempts, it will fail.